# Do loop to conditionally add values SAS

Tags: sas, do-loops

I have a few variables that have values specified.

```
%let a_val=20;
%let b_val=30;
%let c_val=40;
```

I also have a data set that looks like this.

```
data have;
input name $ a b c;
cards;
joe 1 1 2
jim 3 2 3
jak 5 3 5
;
run;
```

Now, I need to create variables p1-p5 that add up the a_vals, b_vals, and c_vals if they match the value.  For example, since joe has a value of 1 for a and b, p1 would be sum of a_val and b_val, which is 50.  The value of p1 will be zero for both jim and jak, since they have no values of 1.  Similarly, p2 will be 0 for jak, 30 for jim, and 40 for joe.

The finished data set would look like this

```
>name p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
>joe  50  40   0   0   0
>jim   0  30  40   0   0
>jak   0   0  30   0  60
```

I tried to do this with a do loop like so:

```
data attempt;
set have;
do i=1 to 5;
p&i=0;
if a=i then p&i=p&i+a_val;
if b=i then p&i=p&i+b_val;
if c=i then p&i=p&i+c_val;
end;
run;
```

Am I on the right track?

Thanks!  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up macro code and data step code here.

One option:

```
data want;
set have;
array p p1-p5;
do _i=1 to 5;
 p[_i] = sum((a=_i)*&a_val,(b=_i)*&b_val,(c=_i)*&c_val);
end;
run;
```

You could conceivably loop through the a-c variables in an array also; if so, then you'd need to use `symget` to get the value of the macro variable associated with the element of the array.  For 3 variables this isn't worth the effort.

This would be something like:

```
data want;
set have;
array p p1-p5;
array var a b c;
do _i=1 to 5;
    do _j = 1 to dim(var);
        p[_i] = sum(p[_i],(var[_j]=_i)*symget(cats(vname(var[_j]),'_val')));
    end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  That makes sense.  I actually do have many more variables than three, so I may look into looking with symget as you suggested.  In the meantime, this definitely helps me get off the ground.  Thanks again.

Comment: Symget appended to answer.